# Setting a Canvas.SetLeft/Right/Bottom/Top outside of certain circular boundaries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Hello, if this question is not clear enough please give me feedback on how I can better describe it in the comments.**

I'm creating a game in WPF, and the player gets XP by winning challenges; I have a circular object in the middle, and whenever the user wins certain challenges a '20 xp' text block will show up randomly on some place on the user's screen.

**Visualisation**

[image]

I do not want the '20 xp' to pop up right in the middle of the player's game; this will be a distraction. It would be best that is pops up outside the boundaries of the game.

EDIT: Current code for handling +20 xp animation:

```
        {
            var tb = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = text,
                RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(x, y),
                FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Light"),
                FontSize = fontSize,

                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,

                Foreground = Brushes.White,

            };
            rootCanvas.Children.Add(tb);

            Random rnd = new Random();


            var opacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 1,
                To = 0,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2)

            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnim, tb);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnim, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));

            var opacityAnimstart = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                To = 1,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)

            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimstart, tb);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimstart, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));

           

            var xAnim = new DoubleAnimation(x, x + 40, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.6)));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnim, tb);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnim, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));



            var xAnim2 = new DoubleAnimation(x + 40, x + 80, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.6)))
            {
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnim2, tb);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnim2, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));




            var yAnim = new DoubleAnimation(y, y - 40, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.3)))
            {
                AutoReverse = true,
                EasingFunction = new BounceEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn, Bounces = 0, },
                RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnim, tb);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnim, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Y"));

            var sb = new Storyboard();

            Canvas.SetTop(tb, rnd.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight)));
            Canvas.SetBottom(tb, rnd.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight)));
            Canvas.SetRight(tb, rnd.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)));
            Canvas.SetLeft(tb, rnd.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)));

            p4.Play();
            sb.Children.Add(opacityAnimstart);
            sb.Children.Add(opacityAnim);
            sb.Children.Add(xAnim);
            sb.Children.Add(yAnim);
            sb.Children.Add(xAnim2);

          

            sb.Begin();
        }
```

For people commenting that this question is 'too broad', yes, I agree with you and I can tell where you're coming from.

Comment: The question is too broad. You haven't even provide any code showing how you present the _"+20 XP"_ text in the first place, so how can any one tell you how to do it differently than you are? That said, I will point out: presumably you know the location and radius of the "circular object". It is also simple to measure the distance from some point to another. So you could just pick random X/Y coordinates, discarding and picking again if the selected coordinates are within the radius of the circular object. Please improve the question, narrowing it to be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Makes sense - I have provided my current code. Good idea I will act upon what you've said.